# Control logic using HTML::Template

Tags: html, perl, templates

Just a couple of quick questions. If I'm writing CGI programs to create web pages via [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Template), then do I have to write separate `tmpl` files for each distinctive screen (the control logic to be in the Perl code)?

Also, (and in a similar area) is it OK to put url links to the other screen CGI programs within the `tmpl` files? For example if one screen displays employee details, could I put a link on the department field to display department details on another screen - I'm guessing I can, but want to know if there are repercussions?

Hmm, maybe they are quick questions, but the answers may be involved, so if anyone knows a good web source that explains this a link would suffice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The whole point of using [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Template) is to separate the V (view) from the MC (model and controller) in [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

I follow the simple rule of one template file per view. Of course, you can use the `<TMPL_INCLUDE>` mechanism to avoid unnecessary duplication.

You can include any links you want in the templates. You are just sending HTML to the browser, anyway.

[CGI::Application](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::Application) works well with [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Template).

Comment: Thanks Sinan. You've stated what I originally guessed, but good to get some confirmation from a guru.